# Rickshaw - js chart library: Need strings instead of numbers on axes

Tags: charts, d3.js, javascript

I am using rickshaw(http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) and want to have strings on one of the axes of the graph instead of numbers. Is it possible to do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own formatter can be defined and be used

```
Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.myFormat =  (y) ->
  if (y == val)
    return 'somestring';
  else
    return ''some other string';
```

Use this as:

```
yAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y
  graph: graph
  tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.myFormat


graph.render()
```